# Tensorflow issue (filenotfound)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a total beginner to python and am trying to use tensorflow to train my own dataset of images using transfer learning and have been following [this](https://blog.francium.tech/build-your-own-image-classifier-with-tensorflow-and-keras-dc147a15e38e) tutorial.

When i get to the following block of code:

```
training_images = train_data_with_label()
testing_images = test_data_with_label()
tr_img_data = np.array([i[0] for i in training_images]).reshape(-1,64,64,1)
tr_lbl_data = np.array([i[1] for i in training_images])
tst_img_data = np.array([i[0] for i in testing_images]).reshape(-1,64,64,1)
tst_lbl_data = np.array([i[1] for i in testing_images])
model = Sequential()
```

I get the following error:

[image: the error]
Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Here is my full code for reference:

[image: full code]

Comment: Well, do you actually have a C:\Users\olive\OneDrive\Documents\Comp sci\Project\Train directory? Also, not a TensorFlow issue.

Comment: Yep i directly copied and pasted the directory from my files. Also, apologies what issue would you say it is?

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. That directory doesn't exist. Check for typos or capitalization. You can confirm if the directory `d` is valid through `os.path.isdir(d)`.

Comment: Hmm i must be mistaken then, i just literally copied my filepath and ran this and returned with false. Do i need to make a directory in a specific way

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, as i thought - it was a trivial error and have now fixed!